# Change JTable cell colours without clicking

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

In a nutshell, I've got a JTable populated with hex data.  The table remains on screen whilst some background processing occurs.

The background processing checks some 8 byte values, and if for example, the first 8 bytes are processed successfully, I need the first 8 cells in the table to change their background colour to green.  This goes on for the next 8, until the end of the table.

But I can't figure out how to achieve this.

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        System.out.println("Cell render test");
        cellComponent.setBackground(java.awt.Color.GREEN);
        return cellComponent;
    }
}
```

This is some code I've found that allows for the rendering of a cell, however it only seems to apply for entire columns, using the:

```
.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setCellRenderer(customRenderer);
```

I guess there are two distinct problems here:

1. How to specify an exact range of cells to apply a custom render to, i.e. row 0, columns 0-7?
2. How to apply this without the user interacting with the table.  A lot of the custom rendering stuff I can find is for when a user selects a cell, but in this instance, no cells are being manually selected.  I'm guessing it might be a case of triggering some kind of event.

If anyone can offer any advice or input, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last arguments to the method are row and column.  To get the required result, the renderer must take those values into account.